# Algebraic version of Riemann Extension Theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

If $\rho: X\dashrightarrow Y$ is a rational map of varieties with $X$ smooth that extends uniquely to a continuous map $\rho': X\rightarrow Y$, is it true that $\rho$ extends to a morphism $X\rightarrow Y$?

If we are working over $\mathbb{C}$, then I think we can locally take charts and apply the fact that, given a holomorphic function $f$ on the open disk $\Delta\subset \mathbb{C}^n$, any bounded holomorphic function on $\overline{\Delta}\backslash\{f=0\}$ extends to a holomorphic function on $\Delta$.

Is there an algebraic way to prove this statement?

Comment: This follows from one formulation of Zariski's Main Theorem.  The point is to consider the closure of the graph of $\rho$ inside the product $X\times Y$.  The Zariski closure equals the analytic closure (for finite type varieties over $\mathbb{C}$).  So then the question is whether the projection of this closure to $X$ is an isomorphism.  If $X$ is normal, this projection is an isomorphism if and only if it has finite fibers, by Zariski's Main Theorem.

Comment: Assume that $X$ is normal (if $X$ is smooth then it is normal) and $Y$ is proper. If we denote by $U$ the open where you rational map $\rho$ is define, then there exists an open $V$ of $X$ containing $U$ and all points of codimension $1$ such that $\rho$ extends to $V$.